# NetworkX average shortest path length and diameter is taking forever

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I have a graph (A) built from unweighted edges, and I would like to compute the average shortest path length for the biggest connected graph (giantC) in my main graph (A). However, the script has been running for more than 3 hours so far (tried on Colab and locally), and no results are output neither for `diameter` nor for `average_shortest_path_length`.

I am using `networkx==2.5`, `python==3.6.9`

and here is my script

```
import logging
import networkx as nx 
from networkx.algorithms.distance_measures import diameter
from networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic import average_shortest_path_length


# graph is built from a json file as follows 
with open('graph.json') as f:
     graph_dict = json.load(f)

_indices = graph_dict['indices']
s_lst, rs_lst= _indices[0], _indices[1]    

graph_ = nx.Graph()
for i in range(len(s_lst)):
     graph_.add_edge(s_lst[i], rs_lst[i])


# fetch the hugest graph of all graphs
connected_subgraphs = [graph_.subgraph(cc) for cc in 
nx.connected_components(graph_)]
logging.info('connected subgraphs fetched.')
Gcc = max(nx.connected_components(graph_), key=len)
giantC = graph_.subgraph(Gcc)
logging.info('Fetched Giant Subgraph')

n_nodes = giantC.number_of_nodes()
print(f'Number of nodes: {n_nodes}') # output is 106088

avg_shortest_path = average_shortest_path_length(giantC)
print(f'Avg Shortest path len: {avg_shortest_path}')

dia = diameter(giantC)
print(f'Diameter: {dia}')
```

Is there any way to make it faster? or an alternative to computing both the diameter and shortest path length for the giantC graph?

Comment: some additional info would be helpful, e.g. what's the number of vertices and edges of the largest component (giantC)? Computing an all-pairs shortest path for large graphs ain't cheap.

Comment: can you advise me on how to fetch such information from this graph? I would gladly do it. Number of nodes is `106,088`

Comment: The formula used to compute the avg shortest path length is given in the [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.average_shortest_path_length.html). The formula requires as input the shortest path length for all vertex pairs. In your case, the component has 106088 vertices. The computational complexity to compute the all-pairs shortest path is O(n^3) (give or take, depending on which alg you use). 106088^3 is a huge number, you will never be able to compute.

Comment: Computing the graph diameter has the time computational complexity, so that won't be any quicker. So in summary, it's unlikely you will be able to compute the desired number exactly. You might want to look at alternative metrics that are easier to compute, or approximate metrics that try to estimate the exact metrics.

Comment: The diameter is tricky but the average shortest path length can often be well estimated by sampling, i.e. take 2 randomly selected nodes and compute the shortest path between them. Repeat 1000 times.

Comment: [Here](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/chechik.pdf) is a paper on estimating the diameter but it is a more involved task.

Comment: I opted for the sampling approach and computed the average of the shortest path length. Thank you for the paper reference I will read it.

Comment: I would like to take a moment to thank you (Joris K.) for letting me know that my task was not that easy to be computed and save my time and more important the computational resources :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future readers,
if you want to fetch the largest connected subgraph from your NetworkX Graph

```py
import networkx as nx
import logging


def fetch_hugest_subgraph(graph_):
    Gcc = max(nx.connected_components(graph_), key=len)
    giantC = graph_.subgraph(Gcc)
    logging.info('Fetched Giant Subgraph')
    return giantC
```

If you want to compute the average shortest path length for your graph we can do that by sampling

```py
from statistics import mean
import networkx as nx
import random


def write_nodes_number_and_shortest_paths(graph_, n_samples=10_000,
                                          output_path='graph_info_output.txt'):
    with open(output_path, encoding='utf-8', mode='w+') as f:
        for component in nx.connected_components(graph_):
            component_ = graph_.subgraph(component)
            nodes = component_.nodes()
            lengths = []
            for _ in range(n_samples):
                n1, n2 = random.choices(list(nodes), k=2)
                length = nx.shortest_path_length(component_, source=n1, target=n2)
                lengths.append(length)
            f.write(f'Nodes num: {len(nodes)}, shortest path mean: {mean(lengths)} \n')
```

Computing `avg_shortest_path_length` as I was informed by Joris Kinable (in the comments) has the complexity of `O(V^3); V = number of nodes`. The same applies for computing the diameter of your graph.

Answer (score 4):

For future readers. In `NetworkX >= 2.6` is available a [diameter approximated metric](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.distance_measures.diameter.html) for both directed and undirected graphs.

Example:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("print(nx.diameter(g))",setup="import networkx as nx; g = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(5000, 0.03, 100)", number=1)
3
224.9891120430002
>>> timeit.timeit("print(nx.approximation.diameter(g))",setup="import networkx as nx; g = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(5000, 0.03, 100)", number=1)
3
0.09284040399961668
```

Note that the approximated metric will compute a *lower bound* with the respect to the exact value.